# Joining tables based on the maximum value group each day

Tags: mysql

Table observasi_data

```
 _________________      
| obsid  | value4 |       
|-------+--------|       
|  4085 |    0   |        
|  4086 |   10   |      
|  4087 |   10   |       
|  4088 |   10   |       
|  4089 |   0    |       
|  4090 |   20   |       
|  4091 |   10   |             
|  4093 |   50   |
```

Table observasi

```
__________________       
| obsid | date   |       
|-------+--------|       
|  4085 |8/1/09  |        
|  4086 |8/1/09  |       
|  4087 |8/1/09  |       
|  4088 |9/1/09  |       
|  4089 |9/1/09  |       
|  4090 |9/1/09  |       
|  4091 |10/1/09 |             
|  4093 |10/1/09 |
```

Then I have query like that

```
SELECT  a.obsid, a.value4, b.date
          FROM observasi_data a
          INNER JOIN observasi b ON a.obsid = b.obsid

          ORDER BY `b`.`date` ASC
```

And then the output will be like that,

```
     ___________________________       
    | obsid  | value4 | date   |       
    |-------+--------|--------|       
    |  4085 |    0   |8/1/09  |        
    |  4086 |   10   |8/1/09  |       
    |  4087 |   10   |8/1/09  |       
    |  4088 |   10   |9/1/09  |       
    |  4089 |   0    |9/1/09  |       
    |  4090 |   20   |9/1/09  |       
    |  4091 |   10   |10/1/09 |             
    |  4093 |   50   |10/1/09 |
```

Now, I wanna find the **MAX value4 each date**, so I had used that query

```
SELECT  a.obsid,MAX(a.value4), b.date
              FROM observasi_data a
              INNER JOIN observasi b ON a.obsid = b.obsid

              GROUP BY b.date
              ORDER BY `b`.`date` ASC
```

But the output become like that

---

```
| obsid  | max(value4) | date   |       
|-------+-------------|--------|       
|  4085 |   10        |8/1/09  |        
|  4088 |   20        |9/1/09  |       
|  4091 |   50        |10/1/09 |
```

As you see, I had got the max value4 each date, but the data in column 'obsid' is **not match** with the value4, I had tried but until now I am still not get the solution.

Comment: where is other tables `observasi_data` and `observasi` ?

Comment: Is obsid and o_id the same? Your data and query have mismatched names.

Comment: @Ravi Already added

Comment: @AbhishekJain already editted

Comment: You cannot apply group by only on b.date. It will throw Error that group by doesn't contain Expression from Select list.

Comment: @AbhishekJain, could you give me some suggestion ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This is one way if you need the obsid as well.

```
Select a.obsid,a.value4,b.date from observasi_data a INNER JOIN observasi b ON a.obsid=b.obsid  where a.obsid IN (Select obsid from new1 where value4 IN (Select MAX(a.value4) from new1 a INNER JOIN new2 b ON a.obsid = b.obsid group by b.date order by b.date asc));
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem completely as obsid isn't a aggregated column and group by cannot be applied to it.